# How to create a list of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to make a list of dictionaries in python. Why don't these three methods produce the same results?

```
A = [{}]*2
A[0]['first_name'] = 'Tom'
A[1]['first_name'] = 'Nancy'
print A

B = [{},{}]
B[0]['first_name'] = 'Tom'
B[1]['first_name'] = 'Nancy'
print B


C = [None]*2
C[0] = {}
C[1] = {}
C[0]['first_name'] = 'Tom'
C[1]['first_name'] = 'Nancy'
print C
```

this is what I get:

```
[{'first_name': 'Nancy'}, {'first_name': 'Nancy'}]
[{'first_name': 'Tom'}, {'first_name': 'Nancy'}]
[{'first_name': 'Tom'}, {'first_name': 'Nancy'}]
```

Comment: In the first case you are creating a list with two elements referenceing the same dict.

Comment: What do you expect? Dictionaries in Python are unordered. If you want to keep the keys ordered, take a look on [```collections.OrderedDict()```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Answer (score 3):

Your first method is only creating one dictionary. It's equivalent to:

```
templist = [{}]
A = templist + templist
```

This extends the list, but doesn't make a copy of the dictionary that's in it. It's also equivalent to:

```
tempdict = {}
A = []
A.append(tempdict)
A.append(tempdict)
```

All the list elements are references to the same `tempdict` object.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Barmar has a very good answer why. I say you how to do it well :)

If you want to generate a list of empty dicts use a generator like this:

```
A = [{}for n in range(2)]
A[0]['first_name'] = 'Tom'
A[1]['first_name'] = 'Nancy'
print (A)
```